# Add more z-index at Actionbar Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I'm using modal page to show out menu when up side arrow, but when showing the modal , it keep cover the actionbar, isn't possible to solve it like add more z-index ?

[image]

Comment: When you are using a modal pageMy understanding is that you want to have a drop down menu - when you click the

Answer (score 0):

Set the `fullscreen` parameter to `true` when you show your modal : https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a modal page, it will always be displayed on top of the other page. It will not be possible to bring the ActionBar to front even with z-index.

My understanding is that you want to have a drop down menu - when you click the side arrow, the content will be visible and when you click on the arrow again - it will disappear. If this is your scenario, you can take a look at this [drop-down plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1323).

If I misunderstood you, please, give some more details about your scenario, so we can suggest some other approach.